# Serial protocol issues porting code from C to Python

Tags: python, serial-port, protocols, pyserial

I'm kind of a beginner with both C and the intricacies of serial communication.  I'll try to provide all the information about this issue that i can; let me know if there's anything additional I should provide that would help.

I'm in the process of porting the communication protocol for a serial device (a micromanipulator) from C to Python, for use in a Python application my lab is developing.  The company has provided us with the source code for a small command line utility used to interface with the device.  Using this logic, our Python module is able to to generate correct/identical data blocks, including the CRC.  However, when a data block (identical to a data block generated by the C code) is sent by the Python code, it receives no response from the device.  Using a serial port monitoring program (Free Serial Port Monitor), I've noticed that the communications between Python and the device differ in some cases from the utility provided by the company.

Here's a screenshot of the log for the provided utility, which works properly.  It shows the sending of one data block and its response, as well the sending of a second data block and the start of the response.

[image: Log Example from utility]

And here's a screenshot of what happens with our Python code; as you can see it sends the data block with no response.

[image: Log example from python]

As for other info that might be useful, I'm using the standard Python serial libraries.  The structure of the data block is 14 ASCII characters, starting with STX and ending with ETX.  The first eight data characters correspond to functions, addresses, values, etc., while the final four characters are the CRC.

As I said, I'm a bit of a noob at this and I really have no idea where to start.  Any advice or assistance, or resources that might help me figure this out would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if there's any more specific info I should provide!

http://reentry.mit.edu/extserialport.c

http://reentry.mit.edu/extserialport.h

Comment: Maybe you should post some of your C and python code.  Perhaps you're not configuring the port the same way.  Are you using flow control?  Also, there's no such thing as "the standard Python serial libraries".  In most cases, people use pyserial.

Comment: What I see in the logs you sent is that original utility uses STX (0x02) as a start of message symbol while you are using SOH (0x01)

Comment: Ah, in that case I'm most likely using PySerial, which I have installed.  I have no idea if  I'm using flow control.  I've messed around a bit with some of the configuration options such as

        self.setDsrDtr(True)
        self.setDTR(True)
        self.setRTS(0)

as an example, to get the indicators on the serial monitor to match the indicators when the C program runs (though I really don't know what im doing here.)

Comment: Thanks Serge, I'll check into that.

Comment: Okay @Serge, I took another look at the file and it appears that for the data block (.21000000EABC.) the first character is 0x02, STX.  As for the preceding data, I don't know what it is or does, but it's not generated by the data block code.  Is it possible that for preliminary communications the start character has to be set to STX?

Comment: many serial devices wait for a "\r" to process the request ... Ive found also...

Comment: @Brendan, yes the data block at the end of conversation starts with STX. what about the rest? What you will understand if I start writing this phrase in Hindi for example and only last two words in English? Your device has some logic inside and has some states. Why do you think that it would give proper answer for properly formed packet if you sent garbage from its point of view beforehand? ;)

Comment: @Serge, this data block is really the only part of said conversation in which I have any understanding what's going on (and which is directly generated by code that I've written; the rest is handled internally by PySerial).  If you have any suggestions for what I should look into to figure this out, please let me know!

Comment: @JoranBeasley, thanks for the suggestion, but no luck with appending a '\r' to the data block or sending it separately immediately after...

Comment: ??? Do you mean that PySerial emits some data without your will? Unfortunately I have no knowledge on python and it's libraries. As we are talking about python, the PySerial most likely is distributed under GPL, so sources are available in the net. Find the sources and analyse what's going on inside that lib

Comment: @TJD, I posted a link to the C code for the serial port interface.  It's at http://reentry.mit.edu/extserialport.c and http://reentry.mit.edu/extserialport.h, if this helps at all.

Comment: @Serge reg. the preliminary data that's being communicated (before the data block), I'm not sure if this data is being sent to the device itself, or if it's informing the Windows API how the connection should be configured. (I'm leaning towards the latter.)  The same sort of data gets sent  by the working program.

Comment: Ok, could you please make one more screenshot with original program that has a second column expanded enough to see the type of IOCTL's perfromed?

Comment: @Serge Here's the working one:

http://imgur.com/m72rw

And here's the one from the Python code:

http://imgur.com/1bNm3

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: fine. and now for your app. sorry for not asking it previous time.

Comment: @Serge Sure, it's at http://reentry.mit.edu/SensapexUnit.py.  It's cobbled together out of code for interfacing with another serial device; main() at the bottom sends the text example.  The stuff after print self.serial_write(charchars) is from the other class, but never gets executed as a response is never received.  The dictionaries at the top are for future use; they do nothing now except for the ASCII characters one.

Comment: @Brendan Callahan - The original C code puts the serial port in raw or non-canonical mode, and seems to use HW flow control.  The C dialog indicates a "Clear RTS" operation, whereas your Python code seems to "Set RTS".  BTW the xmitted "\r" or 0x0D is superfluous and should be removed.  You should use a 'scope, voltmeter or line monitor and compare the states of the HW handshake lines during original-C versus Python transmissions.

Comment: @sawdust, Thanks, that's very helpful to know!  The lines you mentioned, the set RTS and /r, are both commented out; they are from previous tinkering around with the code.  However, I've realized that the standard pyserial library (serial.Serial) doesn't have the options I need to configure these parameters - I found a Win32Serial.py, however, that does seem to have the specific configuration options that are set by the C code, as well as an option for RAW io.  I haven't gotten the code ported over to use this module, but I think I'm on the right track!  Thanks!

Comment: @BrendanCallahan Hi, sorry for the brake. I agree with sawdust that the only valuable difference is in RTS signal. There are two more differences but these should not affect the ability to communicate. Both apps (the original and your) are setting the flow control to DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE (see WinAPI reference) than means that DTR is set to on and remains on. You mentioned that you are using 'standard' Python serial lib. This one: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/ ? If the answer is 'yes' then you may change RTS signal with setRTS(level=True/False) method after initialization of port.

Comment: @Serge, sorry for the late response here, I haven't been in to work since last Friday.  I found that win32serial.py, provided with pyserial, provides direct (bindings?) to the Windows API serial settings, which seems to have worked, after I copied the settings from the C code line by line, including the flow control and RTS.  Thank you very much for your time & assistance!

Comment: Hi @Brendan, from the comments it looks like you may have found the answer yourself?  If so, can you post it in the answers section below and accept it, so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that win32serial.py, provided with pyserial, provides direct (bindings?) to the Windows API serial settings, which seems to have worked, after I copied the settings from the C code line by line, including the flow control and RTS. Thank you very much @Serge for your time & assistance!